# String was not recognized as a valid datetime, source date is 0000-00-00 00:00:000

Tags: c#, mysql

**UPDATE**

Apparently it was not caused by the `0000-00-00 00:00:000`, the program error out when the value was `2016-04-21 00:00:00.000` Any idea what could be the cause?

---

I have a VS C# program that will SELECT from MSSQL then INSERT/ON DUPLICATE UPDATE into MySQL database. I have a particular row which the datetime is `NULL`, my MSSQL query and result are:

**Query**

```
SELECT UserID,LastPasswordDate,
CASE WHEN LastPasswordDate IS NULL THEN '0000-00-00 00:00:00:000' 
    ELSE convert(varchar, LastPasswordDate, 121) END as LastPasswordDate2 from users
    order by LastPasswordDate
```

**Result**

[image]

**C# code**

```
string LastPasswordDate = row["LastPasswordDate"].ToString(); // Or
//DateTime LastPasswordDate = DateTime.ParseExact(row["LastPasswordDate"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", null);

insertUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastPasswordDate", LastPasswordDate);
insertUserCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
insertUserCommand.Parameters.Clear();
tran.Commit();
```

I tried to use C# conversion but keep getting same error message as per title mentioned

Comment: Once you have the data in a datareader/datatable the source you retrieved it from does not matter.

Comment: Just read it into a nullable C# DateTime...   No need to pass by a string....   And then use the null internally, rather than that nasty "zero" date...

Comment: When you check for null you should not return an invalid date. You should return either a valid date or `null`.

Comment: Why can't you store NULL as NULL? If you really must then transfer the dates as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should know is that [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) data type in MySQL has minimum value of `1000-01-01 00:00:00.000`, not `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000` which used as "zero" value display when using datetime conversion for invalid date. Second, the [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) has minimum value of `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000`, not suitable for conversion against MySQL's "zero" value as mentioned before.

If the target column in MySQL DB has nullable `datetime` data type, you should use [`TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) and use `DBNull.Value` for assign null value when the "zero" date cannot be parsed:

```
DateTime date;
DateTime? LastPasswordDate;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(row["LastPasswordDate"].ToString(), out date))
{
    LastPasswordDate = date;
}
else
{
    LastPasswordDate = null;
}

insertUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastPasswordDate", (object)LastPasswordDate ?? DBNull.Value);
insertUserCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But in my thoughts it's better to return null value from T-SQL query and check it with [`Convert.IsDBNull()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.isdbnull?view=netframework-4.7.2), then use `DBNull.Value` for assign null values into database column:

```
DateTime? LastPasswordDate = !Convert.IsDBNull(row["LastPasswordDate"]) ? DateTime.ParseExact(row["LastPasswordDate"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", null) : null;

insertUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastPasswordDate", (object)LastPasswordDate ?? DBNull.Value);
insertUserCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your string '0000-00-00 00:00:00:000' that you are using for the check cannot be converted to a valid date time in code even though it can be saved like that in the database. best solution is to set a default value of null in the database and look for that

Answer (score 0):

In .Net, DateTime.MinValue is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, so 0000-00-00 00:00:00 is outside of the range of valid DateTime values.

see [DateTime.MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)